# Fixed single-elimination tournament probabilities

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a single-elimination bracket style tournament where the number of players *n* = 2<sup>*k*</sup> where *k* > 1. Each player is assigned a seeding of 1 through *n*, and during each round the matchups are uniformly chosen at random. The lower seed always wins in this fixed tournament but the matchups for each round are chosen uniformly at random.

I am trying to find the probability that a specific matchup *i*, *j* will happen in a given round *r*, for example in the first round every pair has an equally likely chance of happening. Another example would be that in the final round, the amount of matchups possible would be *n* / 2 because seed 1 will always make it and their opponents could be seed 1 v 2, ..., *n*/2 + 1.

I don't really know how to find a formula for this, or find a pattern as I have tried and failed, I have made a simulation that gives me rough percentages after running over 1 million tournaments but I need the exact fractions/probabilities, any ideas on how to find these probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix positive integers $k,i,j,r$ with $i < j\le 2^k$ and $r\le k$.

Assume players $i,j$ have ranks $i,j$ respectively.

Given the specified random pairings, our goal is to find the probability, $p$ say, that players $i,j$ meet in round $r$.

No bias is introduced by assuming a single initial random draw with the usual tree structure, followed by deterministic outcomes.

Define events $A,B,C$ as follows . . .

- Let $A$ be the event that players $i,j$ are in separate halves of the same $2^r$-player sub-tree (so they could potentially meet in round $r$).$\\[4pt]$

  Let $B$ be the event that player $j$ wins all matches in the first $r-1$ rounds.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $C$ be the event that player $i$ wins all matches in the first $r-1$ rounds.

Then we have
\begin{align*}
P(A)&=
\frac{2^{r-1}}{2^k-1}
\\[4pt]
P(B{\,|\,}A)&=
{\large{
\frac
{\binom{2^k-j}{2^{r-1}-1}}
{\binom{2^k-2}{2^{r-1}-1}}
}}
\\[4pt]
P(C{\,|\,}A,B)&=
{\large{
\frac
{\binom{2^k-i-2^{r-1}}{2^{r-1}-1}}
{\binom{2^k-1-2^{r-1}}{2^{r-1}-1}}
}}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and then $p=P(A)\,P(B{\,|\,}A)\,P(C{\,|\,}A,B)$, so
$$
p=
\frac{2^{r-1}}{2^k-1}
{\,\cdot\,}
{\large{
\frac
{\binom{2^k-j}{2^{r-1}-1}}
{\binom{2^k-2}{2^{r-1}-1}}
}}
{\,\cdot\,}
{\large{
\frac
{\binom{2^k-i-2^{r-1}}{2^{r-1}-1}}
{\binom{2^k-1-2^{r-1}}{2^{r-1}-1}}
}}
$$
As an example, for $k=4,i=2,j=4,r=3$, we get
$$
p=
\frac{4}{15}
{\,\cdot\,}
{\large{
\frac
{\binom{12}{3}}
{\binom{14}{3}}
}}
{\,\cdot\,}
{\large{
\frac
{\binom{10}{3}}
{\binom{11}{3}}
}}
=
\frac{32}{273}
\approx
.117
$$

Comment: This assumes that players $i$ and $j$ both clear $(r-1)$ rounds. I believe OP's simulation takes into account that one or both may get knocked out before that, which is what makes it complex.

Comment: @true blue anil: I don't assume players $i,j$ win their first $r-1$ rounds. Rather, as part of the calculation of $p$, I compute the _probability_ of that happening.